# FFMPEG: Application provided invalid in convert RTP to HLS

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming, rtp, http-live-streaming

i try to convert a RTP stream from dvb cart to HLS with code :

```
ffmpeg -i rtp://239.1.2.1:60001 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -hls_time 2 -hls_wrap 5 -f hls /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8
```

after i run this code view a warning :

```
[hls @ 0xd0e8c0] Invalid DTS: 6622762 PTS: 6615562 in output stream 0:0
```

and then after some minute show an error that :

```
Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 6611962 >= NOPTS
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

i see this error when try to convert UDP stream too, can anyone help me hoe to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your stream is a h264 you could try `ffmpeg -i rtp://239.1.2.1:60001 -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -hls_time 2 -hls_wrap 5 -f hls /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8` see if that gets rid of your dts error. If you are not using h264 add the name of the code explictly instead of using the `copy`

Also there is a bug recorded here: [DTS bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2212) which might mean you just have to update your ffmpeg.